# JavaFX not on FX application thread

Tags: java, runnable

So I've been given an assignment to make my application check for customers every x seconds through multithreading with Runnable. So I jammed ScheduledExecutorService into my controller class, and the new thread gets called and that's all dandy, but whenever I try making an Alert I get an IllegalStateException.

The class:

```
public class Line implements Runnable
{

    public Line()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm made");
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("I've started");
        try
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Line is empty");
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Line empty");
            System.out.println("I've ended");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the whole run() function into Platform.runLater thing like so:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("I've started");
                try
                {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Line is empty");
                    alert.setTitle("Error");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Line empty");
                    System.out.println("I've ended");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

But then Runnable complains there's no run().

Anyone got any idea how to do this? The code has to be called every x seconds through ScheduledExecutorService, and the alert must be made within the run() function.

Comment: `But then Runnable complains there's no run().` can you show it?

Comment: It says not all methods are implemented, and offers to either add run() method or make the class abstract.
Also, I might have confused you a bit, the second snippet I used is still used within the Line class, not somewhere else in the code where I'd need it used. I am really new to this so I don't even know how I'd use Platform.runLater thing.

Comment: Your use of runLater is correct thought I dont understand where you get that error

Comment: you would need to post full stack if IllegalStateException, that woudl help a lot

Comment: I just get this. I'm probably doing it wrong. http://i.imgur.com/5GSBBpg.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got yourself confused among two different `Runnable`s. Your Line implements `Runnable` and thus have to implement `run` which would be executed by scheduler. But given that you want to relay UI work back to FX thread you need to pass it another Runnable implementation, a la:

```
 public class Line implements Runnable
    {

        public Line()
        {
            System.out.println("I'm made");
        }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
              System.out.println("I've started");
              try
              {
                 Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Line is empty");
                 alert.setTitle("Error");
                 alert.setHeaderText("Line empty");
                 System.out.println("I've ended");
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }});
     }
}
```

Comment: plus1 is the ^ button :)

Comment: I have too low rep so it's not publicly displayed my friend, it should still record on your profile though :)

Comment: you have accepted the answer but did not upvote it, or I dont really see that, but thats fine, the main part is that its worked